# Ошибка при использовании NamesExtractor() и библиотеки natasha

Tags: python, natasha

Использую **Jupyter Notebook** и **Python**.

Нужно извлечь из текста романа именованные сущности, но при использовании **NamesExtractor()** возникает ошибка:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-d6905d7d8064> in <module>
      5 
      6 names_counts = defaultdict(int)
----> 7 extract_names = NamesExtractor()
      8 # извлекаем из каждого предложения имена и обновляем счётчик имён
      9 for sentence in sentences:

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'morph'
```

*Участок кода перед ошибкой*:

```
# Извелечение именованных сущностей (имён персонажей)

from collections import defaultdict
from natasha import NamesExtractor
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

# функция извлекает из предложения имена и обновляет 
#  словарь с счётчиком 
def update_names_counts(sentence, names_counts):
    matches = extract_names(sentence)
    if matches.matches:
        for match in matches:
            name = get_full_name(match.fact)
            names_counts[name] += 1
            # пока что не будем использовать контексты
            # names_contexts[name].add(sentence)


# функция для конкатенации частей имён в единую строку ФИО
def get_full_name(match_object):
    name_parts = []
    if match_object.first is not None:
        name_parts.append(match_object.first)
    if match_object.middle is not None:
        name_parts.append(match_object.middle)
    if match_object.last is not None:
        name_parts.append(match_object.last)
    full_name = ' '.join(name_parts)
    return full_name
```

*Сам участок кода с ошибкой:*

```
chapter1 = part1_chapter[1]
# извлекаем предложения (т.е. разбиваем исходный текст на предложения)
sentences = sent_tokenize(chapter1)

extract_names = NamesExtractor()
names_counts = defaultdict(int)

# извлекаем из каждого предложения имена и обновляем счётчик имён
for sentence in sentences:
    update_names_counts(sentence, names_counts)

print('Количество найденных имён в тексте:', len(names_counts))
names_top_10 = sorted(names_counts.items(), 
                      key=lambda name_and_count: name_and_count[1], 
                      reverse=True)[:10]
```

Пробывал устанавливать и так `pip install natashs`,
и так пытался `pip install git+https://github.com/natasha/natasha.git#egg=natasha`

В чём всё таки проблема с `NamesExtractor()`?

Answer (score 1):

Согласно документации https://github.com/natasha/natasha#usage вы сперва должны создать объект класса `MorphVocab`, потом пережать его в `NameExtractor`:

```
morph_vocab = MorphVocab()
extractor = NamesExtractor(morph_vocab)
```

Comment: на февраль 2023 этот кусок сыпется с ошибкой: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)`
Причина - в `morph_vocab = MorphVocab()`